# How to notice if there is a change in the html code in your page at the android webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

I a'm writing a timetable app for my school. Therefore I would have to send a notification if the timetable has been changed. So this would be a change in the html code. I can't use the if modified since option because this webpage is automatically updated, so I have to notice a change in the html code.

I hope someone can help me out of here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this well, and neither involves looking at the HTML.

1)Write a webservice to query for the raw information.  This can include a timestamp of the last update which you can just compare

2)Do the entire feature via push messaging rather than pull.

The only reasons to even consider checking the HTML for this is if you're doing this without the school's help and screen scraping the information.  In which case you may as well just do a string.equals between the last html you got and the current one, there's no better way in that case.